# convert kafka epoch date to normal salesforce date

Tags: apex, date

I am receiving events from kafka which has logical type date fields

```
"FirstDate": 37367,
"LastDate": 86367,
```

I am trying to convert it salesforce appectable format like below

```
cont.FirstDate__c = convertDate(Integer.valueof(cp.message.FirstDate));
cont.LastDate__c= convertDate(Integer.valueOf(cp.message.LastDate));

 public static Date convertDate(Integer ctdt) {       
        DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(ctdt * 1000);
        system.debug('got this far: ' + dt.date()); 
        return dt.date();
    }
```

I am getting an error `System.TypeException: Invalid integer: Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 37367`

How to covert it into salesforce date format

Comment: Why there is a minus voting to this. i dont understand

Comment: How is `cp.message` declared; if the JSON values are already integers why are you going thru `Integer.valueOf()` expressions?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add days:

```
public static Date convertEpochDays(Integer epochDays) {
  return Date.newInstance(1970, 1, 1).addDays(epochDays);
}
```